# Jquery Not Synchronized with the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I found a new problem where when i manipulate the dom using jquery. The dom is not updated.

Here we go.

```
var PostCard = function($root) {
    this.$root = $root;
    this.stuff_id = this.$root.data('stuff_id');
    this.id = this.$root.data('id');
    this.is_owner = this.$root.data('is_owner');
    this.$propose_button = null;
    this.$favorite_button = null;
    this.init();
    this.initEvents();
};

PostCard.prototype.init = function () {
        this.$propose_button = this.$root.find("." + PostCard.prototype.CSS_CLASSES.PROPOSE_BUTTON);
this.$proposal_box_modal = this.$root.find("." + PostCard.prototype.CSS_CLASSES.PROPOSAL_MODAL);
this.$proposal_box = this.$root.find("." + PostCard.prototype.CSS_CLASSES.PROPOSAL_BOX);
this.$favorite_button = this.$root.find(".post-card-button-favorite");
this.$total_favorite = this.$root.find('.post-card-total-favorite');
this.$image_view_editor = this.$root.find("#" + this.id + "-image-view");
this.image_view_editor = new ImageViewEditor(this.$image_view_editor);
this.proposal_box = new HomeProposalBox(this.$proposal_box);

};

PostCard.prototype.initEvents = function() {
    var self =this;
    $(document).on("click", "#" + this.id,function(e) {

        if(e.target && $(e.target).hasClass('post-card-button-propose') ){
            if(self.is_owner ) {
            return false;
            }   
            if(CommonLibrary.isGuest()) {
                return false;
            }
            self.$proposal_box_modal.modal("show").load($(this).attr("value"));
        } else if(e.target && $(e.target).hasClass('post-card-button-favorite')) {
            self.clickFavoriteButton_();
        }
    });


PostCard.prototype.clickFavoriteButton_ = function() {
        this.markFavorite();
};

PostCard.prototype.markFavorite = function() {

    this.$favorite_button.addClass('post-card-button-red');  
};
```

When Favorite button is clicked, the `clickFavoriteButton()` will be trigerred, and `markfavorite` method will be fired next.
The problem is although `this.$favorite_button` is updated (the class is added to the variable), the dom in the page is not updated
this only happens to dynamically loaded element, and does not happen to element that has been around since the page is loaded.

The PostCard is created in PostList class

```
/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */


var PostList = function($root) {
    this.$root = $root;
    this.stuff_ids = '';
    this.id = $root.data('id');
    this.location = $root.data('location');
    this.query = '';
    this.post_cards = [];
    this.$post_list_area = null;
    this.permit_retrieve_post = true;
    this.init();
    this.initEvents();
};


PostList.prototype.SCROLL_VALUE = 95;

PostList.prototype.init = function() {
    $.each($(".post-card"), function(index, value) {
        this.post_cards.push(new PostCard($(value))); 
        if(this.stuff_ids === '' ) {
            this.stuff_ids += $(value).data('stuff_id');
        } else {
            this.stuff_ids += "," + $(value).data('stuff_id');   
        }
    }.bind(this));

    this.$post_list_area = this.$root.find('.post-list-area');
};

PostList.prototype.initEvents = function() {
    $(window).scroll({self:this}, this.retrievePostWhenScroll_);
};

PostList.prototype.retrievePostWhenScroll_ = function(e) {
    var self = e.data.self;
    var scrollPercentage = 
            ((document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) / 
            (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight) * 100);
    if(scrollPercentage > PostList.prototype.SCROLL_VALUE) {
        if(self.permit_retrieve_post) {
            self.permit_retrieve_post = false;
            $.ajax({
                url: $("#base-url").val() + "/site/get-more-posts",
                type: 'post',
                data: {'ids' : self.stuff_ids, query: self.query, location: self.location},
                success: function(data) {
                    var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
                    if(parsedData['status'] === 1) {
                        self.$post_list_area.append(parsedData['view']);
                        $(parsedData['view']).filter('.post-card').each(function(index, value) {
                            self.post_cards.push(new PostCard($(value)));
                            self.stuff_ids += "," + $(value).data('stuff_id');
                        });
                    }
                    self.permit_retrieve_post = true;
                },
                error : function(data) {
                    self.permit_retrieve_post = true;

                }
            });   
        }
    }

};
```

When you scroll the page, the retrieveWhenScroll method will be fired and PostCard will be dynamically added

Comment: Where is the `$favorite_button` declared? Actually it is just `null`. Show us the full code please.

Comment: You'll have to do an [mcve], ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button).

Comment: i just updated the code, it is in init method

Comment: At a total **guess**, I'd say you're replacing the button with the `self.$proposal_box_modal.modal("show").load($(this).attr("value"));` call. But again, we really can't help with the question as it is.

Comment: dynamic means the element is created after the page is loaded and ready

Comment: I just updated the question, the PostList created the PostCard when the page is scrolled

Comment: `this.$favorite_button` contains a static set of elements that never change when your page changes unless you call `this.init()` again.  In general, it is a bad idea to store away prebuilt jQuery objects when you have a dynamically changing DOM.  Just remake the jQuery objects when you want to carry out the operation and they will always reflect the lastest state of the page.

Comment: i just know that, but will it be slower since the javascript has to find the dom again ?

Comment: It's completely irrelevant if it's slower because it works and your current method does not. In any case it will take just fractions of a millisecond. You won't be able to notice any difference in performance.

Comment: thank you so much Juhana, jfriend00, TJ Crowder